# Passing a 2D array of structs to a function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, arguments, implicit-conversion, function-call

I'm trying to pass a 2D array of structs into a function, but I am receiving a compilation error of conflicting types.
Any help?

```
typedef struct{
    int height;
    int width;
} Size;

Size chart[4][4];

void compare_size(Size x[][4]){
    if(x[1][1].height > x[1][1].width)
        return 1;
}

compare_size(chart[4][4]);
```

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'compare_size'
     compare_size(chart[4][4]);
     ^
note: expected 'struct Size (*)[4]' but argument is of type 'Size'
void compare_size(Size x[][4])
```

Comment: `chart[4][4]` is a single element in the array of arrays. And one out of bounds. If it wasn't a "2D" array, just a plain "1D" array, how would you pass it then?

Answer (score 0):

In this call

```
compare_size(chart[4][4]);
```

you are using an element of the array `chart` with non-valid indices.

You have to write

```
compare_size(chart);
```

provided that `chart` is indeed an array declared somewhere else.

In this case the expression chart is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `Size ( * )[4]`.